How to fetch data of users entering into journey and data of users in wait period activities in journey builder
Please assist with the below details on how to fetch data of the users:
a) How can we fetch data of the users entering into the journey using SFMC reports or any source for KPI.
b) How can we fetch data of the users waiting in activities before receiving the next flow of emails using SFMC reports or any source for KPI.

What research have you done? What have you tried? Where are you stuck? I should hope that by now you know that you need to include as much detail as possible.

Also, your low rate of accepting answers may discourage some people from trying to help you.

we do not have any specific report available to see all users entering the data by a report.
There is a solution mentioned in Stack exchange and you can probably refer to that, its also related to a question.
Can we extract data of contacts that entered a journey and are not a part of email activity in Journey builder
Subscribers currently in a Journey
